# Force Direct3D anti-aliasing in a Direct3D game?

Tags: gaming, nvidia-graphics-card, anti-aliasing, direct3d

Some old games look really jagged nowadays on large displays without any anti-aliasing, but don't have any option built-in to the game to enable it.

On a PC with an NVIDIA graphics card, it's possible to force anti-aliasing in the NVIDIA control panel which can really improve this.  But I'm playing the game in Parallels on a Mac, and although the Mac has an NVIDIA graphics card, it's Parallels' emulated card that Windows sees and so obviously there's no NVIDIA control panel.

Is there some generic way I can force anti-aliasing for a Direct3D game without using the NVIDIA control panel?

Comment: Support for this is specific to the driver itself.  Its very unlikely you will find a driver with the capability to work within Parallels. that can do this.

Comment: Parallels has its own drivers, and they don't have a control panel like the NVIDIA drivers do.  That's why I was wondering if there was a more generic way to force this in D3D.

Comment: The drivers would have to support that method which very unlikely.

Comment: Note re: the Mac and Parallels tags added: I'm just looking for a _generic_ way to force anti-aliasing for a Direct3D game that is not dependent on particular drivers.  Although a way to do this with the Parallels drivers would be great, that's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force [SMAA](http://www.iryoku.com/smaa) on a DirectX 9, 10 or 11 game by using **[injectSMAA](http://mrhaandi.blogspot.com/p/injectsmaa.html)**. It should work with any graphics card brand.

> Description
>
> - adds "Subpixel Morphological Antialiasing" to an application
> - is based on "injectFXAA" (written by "some dude")
> - is supposed to work only with directx 9, directx 10, directx 11, x86 applications
> - may be incompatible with any other form of antialiasing
> - may be incompatible with overlays (Steam Overlay, MSI Afterburner, Fraps, ...)
>
> SMAA is a very efficient GPU-based MLAA implementation, capable of
>   handling subpixel features seamlessly, and featuring an advanced
>   pattern detection & handling mechanism.
>
> http://www.iryoku.com/smaa/

injectSMAA screenshots from the game, Halo: Combat Evolved ([does not have an in-game anti-aliasing (AA) option and does not support graphics driver-forced AA](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Halo:_Combat_Evolved#Anti-aliasing_.28AA.29)):

<sup>Click image thumbnails below to view higher-resolution, original-sized image.</sup>
No AA:
[image]

With SMAA:
[image]

<sup>Screenshots source: http://mrhaandi.blogspot.com/p/injectsmaa.html (more screenshots from other games from the same webpage)</sup>

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be relevant to the question you're asking because I'm not sure it can introduce anti-aliasing into a game that doesn't support it.

But if you're looking to improve the general graphics quality of games that use DirectX 9, you might want to consider using a modded DirectX driver. I know of one popular mod called [`ENB Series`](http://enbdev.com/description_en.htm) that can help improve the overall graphics quality of a game.

However, it does require spending a lot of time tinkering with a lot of settings to get it "just right". The mod works for old DX9 games like [Deus Ex](http://enbdev.com/ss_deusex_en.htm) as well as newer games like [GTA IV](http://gtabay.cba.pl/index_dokumentacja_gta4_en.htm).

Here are a few screenshots of the mod in action (for Deus Ex. [Complete screens here](http://enbdev.com/ss_deusex_en.htm)):

[image: ENB Mod: Deus Ex]

To see a detailed analysis of the mod can do, read the [GTA IV optimization guide for ENB Series mod](http://gtabay.cba.pl/index_dokumentacja_gta4_en.htm).

### Update:

[image: SweetFX]
I found out about another shader injector tool called [SweetFX](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=368880). It's based on [InjectSMAA](http://mrhaandi.blogspot.in/p/injectsmaa.html) and improves upon it and other similar tools like InjectFXAA and FXAAtool (according to its own admission)

You can download SweetFX [from here](http://www.guru3d.com/files_details/sweetfx_shader_suite_download.html). However, it will **only** work on `32-bit DirectX 9, 10 and 11` games.

Luckily, this tool has a lot of tutorial/configuration videos for it created by the gamer community, so it is highly recommended that you watch [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v21m_p7d2A4) [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxFOx-9wZPM) to get better acquainted with the tool.

There's also a configuration tool available called [SweetFX Configurator](http://sweetfx.thelazy.net/) that eases the configuration building.

Here's a list of effects that SweetFX supports (from the [forum post](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=368880)):

```
* SMAA Anti-aliasing : Anti-aliases the image using the SMAA technique - see http://www.iryoku.com/smaa/
* LumaSharpen : Sharpens the image, making details easier to see
* Bloom : Makes strong lights bleed their light into their surroundings
* HDR : Mimics an HDR tonemapped look
* Technicolor : Makes the image look like it was processed using a three-strip Technicolor process - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor
* Cineon DPX : Makes the image look like it was converted from film to Cineon DPX. Can be used to create a "sunny" look.
* Lift Gamma Gain : Adjust brightness and color of shadows, midtones and highlights (avoids clipping)
* Tonemap : Adjust gamma, exposure, saturation, bleach and defog. (may cause clipping)
* Vibrance : Intelligently saturates (or desaturates if you use negative values) the pixels depending on their original saturation.
* Curves : Contrast adjustments using S-curves.
* Sepia : Sepia tones the image - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepia_tone#Sepia_toning
* Vignette : Darkens the edges of the image to make it look more like it was shot with a camera lens. - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting )
* Dither : Applies dithering to simulate more colors than your monitor can display. This lessens banding artifacts - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering#Digital_photography_and_image_processing )
* Splitscreen : Enables the before-and-after splitscreen comparison mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an answer since i don't have parallels myself, but you may want to try running NvidiaInspector.

It'll forcefully change the AA settings of games if you have a nvidia gpu. (Try running it on the windows platform)